# Compiling pHash for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arm, phash

How to compile pHash for `iOS`?

I read the documentation but there's no mention of `iOS/arm` and `Google` doesn't help.

So if anyone was able to compile pHash for iOS please share your experience.

Comment: @CodaFi I managed to compile for Mac with Homebrew and applying a patch from [Wulfshade](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/9343)

Comment: Can be somewhat tedious, see my post here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452712/how-to-build-phash-on-macosx-lion-using-latest-ffmpeg-devel

Comment: @AnriDigholm +1 for that, but I managed to compile for Mac with Homebrew - the problem is iOS

Comment: pHash and any GPL-ed component cannot be used of iOS because the App Store terms are incompatible with GPL. So, you better put your efforts into finding an alternative...

Comment: GPL is not a problem - pHASH also has a commercial license available.

Comment: @AndreiStoleru did you succeeded ?

Comment: @Pierre actually no. In the end I "re-wrote" pHash in Objective-C (with support for Accelerate framework)

Comment: @AndreiStoleru did you open sourced it ? :D

Comment: @Pierre no, it was for a client. I'll ask my client if he's ok with open sourcing the code

Comment: @AndreiStoleru ok cool :) I think that's not hard to convert it. I just need the audio part so I can ignore CImg things.

Comment: @Pierre My library will not be of much use in this case. I wrote it with perceptual hashing of images in mind and all the calculations are based on this :(

Comment: @AndreiStoleru of no problem :) I'll write it for audio hash myself. Thx !

Answer (score 1):

If you need pHash for imageHash purposes, You might consider looking into the imageMagick framework for iOS : http://www.imagemagick.org/download/iOS/

Also, you should remember that pHash is licensed under GPLv3, which means that derived work can only be distributed under the same license terms.

Comment: pHash also has a commercial license so GPL is not a problem.

I had a look at imagemagick but it seems it has the same problems when it comes to iOS.

Comment: imageMagick does image hash for exact identical pixels, while pHash is a project that could compare the hash of resized, distorsion, cropping images.