# Brew formula for pHash

Tags: macos, homebrew, phash

After a couple of days of Googling and trying various suggestions, I am setting aside trying to build pHash for MacOS Sierra from source.  Then one comment pointed to several issues with using Brew to build pHash.  After going down several paths unsuccessfully, I thought I'd just ask if anyone had a formula for pHash that works for MacOS Sierra.

Comment: Quick google found this if you want to try building it yourself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452712/how-to-build-phash-on-macosx-lion-using-latest-ffmpeg-devel

Comment: Might be related; https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/49268
You may be able to build if you use an old ffmpeg, also https://github.com/azr/phash/issues/3

Comment: Thank you for the quick suggestions. In the end I was not successful in building with Brew. I WAS able to finally build pHash from source only by disabling video and audio hashes with the configure flags "--disable-video-hash --disable-audio-hash". For those who might be following this, it finally occurred to me that pHash does not build as an explicit "pHash" executable but rather as a library of pHash functions. The examples directory in the pHash-0.9.6 GitHub source tree has an example command file - test_image - which builds an executable to actually use the pHash functionality.